# how to set a breakpoint at the NSObject class method alloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, lldb

I read the book 《Pro Multithreading and Memory Management for iOS and OS X with ARC, Grand Central Dispatch, and Blocks》, it says as follow:

> As I said earlier, the source code of the NSObject class itself is not publicly available. We investigate how the implementation works using an Xcode debugger (lldb) for iOS application. First, set a breakpoint at the NSObject class method alloc. See what happens on the debugger. The following is the list of functions called inside alloc.

```
+ alloc
+ allocWithZone:
class_createInstance
calloc
```

I know the symbol breakpoint can make the application break when the symbol happen, but how to set a breakpoint at the alloc to know the list of functions called inside it? or, I just misunderstand the thought of the author?

Comment: How about `br s -n "+[NSObject alloc]"`?